# Ring3 API hooking if statement doesn't work

Tags: c#, hook

You may know that antiviruses are detecting files by changing the first few instructions of an API with a jmp instruction that would redirect the execution flow to its own hook handler function. That way AV would register the execution of this API with all parameters lying on the stack at that moment. I want to make something similar, when something (third-party software) hooks some APIs in a child process (made by CreateProcessA/W) for example `MessageBoxA` to execute the if statement with API hooked message.

What I have so far:

```
IntPtr address = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("user32.dll"), "MessageBoxA");

if (address == IntPtr.Zero)
    Console.WriteLine("Function not found in the DLL or load failed");

Console.WriteLine(address);

if (address == (IntPtr)0xE9 || address == (IntPtr)0x90 || address == (IntPtr)0xC3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("API hooked");
}
```

The address is being calculated well but the if statement `address == (IntPtr)0xE9...` is not working because my address is always different than those values which are supposed to be jmp, nop and ret. Where is the problem?

Comment: You want to compare the first three bytes `address` is pointing to. That means using pointers (`byte*`). That means using `unsafe` code. I recommend 1) not doing this in C# and 2) not doing this at all, because this is by far not the only way an AV (or malware) could hook API functions, and even if it did, it could actually hide these shenanigans from you, and even if it didn't do *that*, it could use other instructions than the one you're checking for. Is this a purely intellectual exercise or do you actually need some sort of "security"?

Comment: I just tried with unsafe code and ``byte*`` but it didn't suceedd. Do you know any method else to achieve that?